# Override templateNameParser class with the custom bundle's config file?

Tags: symfony

I want to override the templating.name_parser.class but I would like to do some within the custom config bundle which is loaded after the FrameworkBundle. Right now what I do is:

1. place the config file inside the customBundle/Resources/config/
2. Re-run the templating pass by adding this to the custom bundle:

   $container->addCompilerPass(new TemplatingPass());

I wonder if this is the best way to do so? (I know I can place the config inside the app/config) but I would like to place this config inside the customBundle if possible to make sure all the bundle's specific config is placed inside the package.

Comment: I think the suggestion from SF has pointed me to the right place: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html. I will do more research to see if this inheritance does help me, if it doesn't I will re-open this question. Can a moderator help me to close this for now?

Comment: you can answer the question yourself and after 24 hours mark that question as accepted. If it don't work you can delete/unaccept that answer and we can help you again.